# Arrastrar fórmula hasta celda determinada vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo esta hoja de excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mediante una macro, quiero arrastrar la fórmula de I2 hasta la última fila que contiene datos de la columna A (Matrícula). Así, en este caso sería hasta la fila 15. 
El problema es que esa columna no va a estar rellena siempre hasta la fila 15, por lo que tendría que comprobar primero hasta que fila esta rellena y después arrastrar la fórmula de I2 hasta esa fila, y no sé hacerlo.

La macro que tengo hecha es la siguiente:

```
    Sub Notaexamen_6ejercicios()
'
' Notaexamen_6ejercicios Macro
'

'
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=-1
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RC[-6]*R10C[4]+RC[-5]*R10C[5]+RC[-4]*R10C[6]+RC[-3]*R10C[7]+RC[-2]*R10C[8]+RC[-1]*R10C[9]"
    Range("I2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I15"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("I2:I15").Select
    Range("M18").Select
End Sub
```

¿Cómo debería editarla?

Gracias

Comment: Arrastrar es una acción que se realiza con el ratón, el término sería rellenar abajo (fill down). Te lo menciono porque este tipo de detalles te pueden ayudar a encontrar respuestas en la documentación oficial :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero tienes que encontrar hasta que fila esta llena:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
While Not Cells(i, 1) = ""
    Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 32
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

luego solo cambias tu rango al nuevo que termina en la ultima fila

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(i-1, 9)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

el ejemplo completo quedaria:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
While Not Cells(i, 1) = ""
    Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 32
    i = i + 1
Wend

ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=-1
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RC[-6]*R10C[4]+RC[-5]*R10C[5]+RC[-4]*R10C[6]+RC[-3]*R10C[7]+RC[-2]*R10C[8]+RC[-1]*R10C[9]"
    Range("I2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(i-1, 9)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("I2:I15").Select
    Range("M18").Select
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien. Muchas gracias
Lo único, he eliminado la línea de `Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 32` ya que pintaba las celdas contadas de azul y sin ella, el código sigue funcionando bien.

Comment: Se pueden crear funciones que concatenen otras funciones y obtener el resultado que deseamos. El código queda mucho más limpio y aumenta considerablemente el rendimiento.

Answer (score 1):

Que nadie se lleve a engaño, estas simples líneas eliminan por completo cualquier necesidad de crear más código del que se muestra en esta respuesta.

Estas líneas **detectan** la última fila, **seleccionan** el rango a copiar y **copian** la fórmula desde, en este caso, la Celda I2. Obtenemos un tres en uno sin bucles *for* ni *while* ni *if*.

Haz un copy/paste del ejemplo tal cual y ejecútalo en tu hoja teniendo en cuenta que solo necesitarás una de las sentencias.

```
Sub Notaexamen_6ejercicios()

    'Hasta la primera celda en blanco
    Range("I2", "I" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row) = Range("I2").Formula

    'Hasta la última celda escrita
    Range("I2", "I" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = Range("I2").Formula

End Sub
```

¡Ojo!, nunca las incluyas en

***Private Sub Worksheet_Change()***

ya que es el disparador de eventos por excelencia y haría entrar en bucle a Excel